# Stop AddThis buttons from sliding into place

Tags: addthis

I am using the [AddThis](https://www.addthis.com/) Sharing Sidebar.

Every time a page loads, the sidebar slides into position from the center of the screen.

How can I stop this sliding animation?

I just want the Sharing Sidebar on the side of my page, without any sliding animation.

Comment: The sliding animation is probably connected to a JavaScript `$(document).ready` function or something similar. Is the JavaScript hosted on your site or at AddThis? If it is at your site, look for the appropriate `$(document).ready` code and squash the transition/animation.

Without more code, I'm afraid we can't help you too much.

Comment: the javascript is hosted on the AddThis site. If there are options to remove the sliding animation I cant find them. This is an issue with AddThis, and not Javascript code. Their FAQs and Help Resources are fairly basic so I came here instead. Have you used AddThis before?

Comment: I have not. But I assume they give you a script snippet that contains a link to the JS file hosted on their site. So in order to stop the event from firing you need to know its reference and then you can use JS on your end to kill it before it happens. Another workaround would be to use a CSS animation to hide the slide effect. However, the CSS "fix" is more of a hack and shouldn't be your first choice.

Comment: Ive already got a hack-y fix, I was after a proper solution, presumably from someone who has used the product in question. Ive been web developing for 15+ years, and I totally get how JS / CSS / animations work. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: Could you post the smalled code possible that replicates the problem? That way we can look into what's wrong rather than simply guessing.

Comment: @Moustach There isnt anything wrong, there isnt a problem to fix as such. The only way anybody is going to be able to help me with this is by going to AddThis, putting one of their Sharing Sidebars onto a page, and then, voila, when you view the page you will see the animated slide effect. This effect isn't a bug to fix, and it isn't anything to do with my code. This effect is written and deployed by AddThis. Either I am missing an option on the AddThis website, or I am missing some API functionality from the AddThis website, or possibly someone knows of another way to disable the effect.

Comment: @Jimmery: I do not have an AddThis account but I'd love to give it a try. Could you make a Codepen or something with the AddThis snippet so I can try to find how to change its behavior?

Comment: Can you show me the code of the addthis please...

Comment: Did you try removing the css classes `addthis-animated` and/or `slideInLeft` from the _div_ tag with id **at4-share** ?

Comment: @AhsN leave this as an answer, you are the only person here who seems to know what they are talking about...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try removing the css classes `addthis-animated` and/or `slideInLeft` from the *div* tag with *id* `at4-share` ?

Comment: not tried this yet, but you can have the bounty because you are literally the only person here who seems to have used AddThis before, and instead of just blindly asking for code, you are offering a suggestion of what to try... many thanks!